# How to properly hash body and headers with PHP for dkim?

Tags: php, hash, dkim

I've gone through Eric Vyncke's PHP [dkim script](http://php-dkim.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/php-dkim/php-dkim/) and copied how he was doing hashes for DKIM headers set in emails

```
$DKIM_bh = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($body)));
```

Would be used as so:

```
'bh='.$DKIM_bh.';'//...
```

However when I [validate the email message](http://www.appmaildev.com/en/dkim/) it tells me that the hash doesn't match.

```
$headers .= 'DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/simple; q=dns/txt; bh=';//...

$body = 'Test PHP+SMTP authenticated email,3.';

bh='.base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($body))).';';//...
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing? **How** do I properly hash the body and headers so I can set the DKIM values for the header properly?

Answer (score -1):

Here is example functions how to send emails with dkim and php mail() function:

https://github.com/breakermind/PHP-DKIM

Works on Gmail.com and multipart/mixed messages with attachments!

```
<?php
// Send simple email without DKIM SIgning
// YOUR E-MAIL
$name = 'Name Jony';
$sender = 'sdsdso@domain.pl';
$to = 'ffffu@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Simple html message with dkim';

$headers =
'MIME-Version: 1.0
From: "'.$name.'" <'.$sender.'>
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf8';

$message =
'<html>
    <header></header>
    <body>
        Hello, this a DKIM test e-mail
    </body>
</html>';

// NOW YOU WILL DO (after setting up the config file and your DNS records) :
// Make sure linefeeds are in CRLF format - it is essential for signing
$message = preg_replace('/(?<!\r)\n/', "\r\n", $message);
$headers = preg_replace('/(?<!\r)\n/', "\r\n", $headers);

require_once 'mail-signature.class.php';
require_once 'mail-signature.config.php';

$signature = new mail_signature(
    MAIL_RSA_PRIV,
    MAIL_RSA_PASSPHRASE,
    MAIL_DOMAIN,
    MAIL_SELECTOR
);
$signed_headers = $signature -> get_signed_headers($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

// Send email
ini_set('sendmail_from', $sender);
echo mail($to, $subject, $message, $signed_headers.$headers);
die();
```

Comment: Please don't post your example everywhere you can find; can I ask you to please read [How to offer personal open-source libraries?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/229085)

Comment: The URL https://github.com/breakermind/PHP-DKIM doesn't works